# Warum heißen Tomaten in Österreich „Paradeiser“?

Tags: austrian

Ich habe Paradeissuppe bestellt -- und Tomatensuppe gekriegt. Ich kann einige österreichische Worte verstehen (etwa *Erdapfel*, weil *pomme de terre* oder *aardappel* dieselbe Etymologie haben). Aber bei *Paradeis* hilft einem nichts:

- Warum nennt man in Österreich die Tomaten *Paradeiser*? Stimmt [das](http://www.oesterreichisch.net/oesterreich-1-Paradeiser.html?letter=P)?

Comment: The _Paradies_ (=paradise) connection sounds plausible to me. The word is on its way out, these days. "Tomate" is fine, even in Austria.

Comment: Ich kenne den Begriff "Paradeiser" noch aus meiner Kindheit, von der Donauschwäbischen Urgroßmutter. Im Ungarischen (paradicsom) und Serbischen (paradajz) ist derselbe Wortstamm erkennbar.

Comment: s.a. http://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradeiser

Comment: @c.p.: Der Link scheint den Weg des Internets zu gehen: es ist halb gestorben. Ist es möglich, nach 6 Jahren noch den Teil zu zitieren, der damals mit "stimmt das" gemeint war? https://www.oesterreichisch.net/wort/1/Paradeiser enthält mehrere Einträge, der erste auf "Tomate" liefert die meisten Kommentare.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Die Seite oesterreichisch.net ist zwar gut gemeint aber mit Vorsicht zu genießen. Da werden Ausdrücke der österreichischen Standardsprache wild mit Dialektausdrücken vermengt. Auf der Startseite steht zwar, dass die Seite Dialektwörter sammeln will, aber gerade *»Paradeiser«* ist ein schönes Beispiel für ein Wort, das eben genau **kein** Dialektwort ist, und trotzdem auf dieser Seite steht. ...

Comment: ... Das Wort *»Paradeiser«* steht in zahlreichen österreichischen Gesetzen und Verordnungen (z.B: Fruchtsaftverordnung, Pflanzenschutzverordnung, Konfitürenverordnung, Qualitätsklassenverordnung usw. aber auch im EU-Beitrittsvertrag), die alle in österreichischem Standarddeutsch, also nicht in irgend einem Dialekt verfasst wurden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Danke, die Einordnung der Seite hinsichtlich Qualität verstehe ich. Mir geht es jedoch nicht um die Seite an sich, sondern um den relevanten Teil für "stimmt das", was vor 6 Jahren hier ein Teil der Frage war. Und ich kann jetzt nicht mehr erkennen, was genau denn stimmen sollte oder auch nicht.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Keine Zeit, sorry. Jeder könnte nun die Frage verbessern.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eva reichte Adam im Paradies einen Apfel. Das ist der Paradiesapfel. So bezeichnete man früher auch besonders auffallend rote Äpfel. Das »Paradies« (i-e) hieß aber auch »Paradeis« (e-i).

### Paradeiser

Als dann Kolumbus Amerika entdeckt hat, kamen kurz danach viele neue Früchte nach Europa. Unter anderem eine Frucht, die einem Apfel recht ähnlich sah, und auffallend rot war. Also nannte man diese Frucht im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums »Paradeis-Apfel«. Vom Pardeisapfel war es dann nicht weit zum Paradeiser.

### Erdäpfel

Zur selben Zeit kam auch eine knollige Frucht nach Europa, die unter der Erde wuchs. Sie sah ebenfalls einem Apfel oder einer Birne ähnlich. Also hieß diese Frucht »Erd-Apfel« bzw. »Grund-Birne«. Die »Grumba« findet man noch im Dialekt des Südburgenlandes, während der Erdapfel sich als Name in ganz Österreich durchsetzte.

### Kukuruz

Zeitgleich kam eine dritte Feldfrucht aus Amerika nach Europa. Es ist eine mannshoch wachsende Getreideart, deren Ähren so groß sind, dass man sie Kolben nennt. Sie wurde über Ungarn nach Österreich eingeführt. In Österreich erhielt diese Getreideart daher einen Namen, der auf die Kuruzen, ein in Ungarn lebendes Volk, zurückgeht: Kukuruz. Ich weiß aber nicht, wie weit nach Westen der Name Kukuruz für den Mais verbreitet ist.

---

**Ergänzung Dezember 2021:**

Im Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache ist kürzlich das Ergebnis einer Befragung über die Verbreitung von Tomate/Paradeiser veröffentlicht worden. Da es gut zur Frage passt, ergänze ich es hier.

[image: Verbreitung von Tomate/Paradeiser]
<sup>[Quelle](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r12-f1d/?child=runde)</sup>

Das Ergebnis hat mich sehr überrascht, weil ich dachte, das Wort wäre in ganz Österreich verbreitet, was wohl falsch ist. Es wird aber nur in Wien, Niederösterreich, dem Burgenland, Teilen der Steiermark (West- und Oststeiermark sowie die östliche Hälfte der Obersteiermark) sowie Teilen Kärntens (Unterkärnten) häufiger verwendet als *»Tomate«*. Diese Region ist aber dichter besiedelt als die übrigen Gebiete, so dass trotzdem 60% aller Österreicher in einem Gebiet leben, in dem *»Paradeiser«* die häufigere Variante ist. Tatsächlich verwenden aber deutlich weniger Österreicher dieses Wort, weil sich vielerorts die *»Tomate«* anschickt, die *»Paradeiser«* zu überholen, was vor allem daran liegt, dass die älteren Benutzer des Wortes *»Paradeiser«* langsam aussterben, während die jüngeren Österreicher in ihrem täglichen Medienkonsum (hauptsächlich Internet, aber auch Kabel- und Satelliten-Fernsehen sowie aus Deutschland importierte Zeitschriften) fast ausschließlich mit dem Wort *»Tomate«* konfrontiert sind. Selbst in Supermärkten wird das Gemüse mittlerweile kaum noch also *»Paradeiser«* in den Werbebroschüren geführt, sondern fast nur noch als *»Tomate«.* Es ist also damit zu rechnen, dass dieses Wort in wenigen Jahrzehnten auch in Österreich ausgestorben sein wird (so wie viele andere Begriffe des österreichischen Deutsch).

Auf DiÖ erschien heuer im Juni ebenfalls ein Artikel zu diesem Thema, in dem sehr ausführlich die Frage erörtert wird, wie die Österreicher diese Frucht nennen: [Nun sag: Wie hast du’s mit … "Tomaten" und "Paradeiser"?](https://www.dioe.at/artikel/2935)

Comment: Und: Die Grund-Birne gibt es im Schwäbischen als "Grombira" noch heute. Ich find's immer wieder schön zu sehen, wie die Begriffe die Donau runter und ggf. wieder zurück gewandert sind.

Comment: Interessante Antwort! (Zum letzten Satz: Im Russischen sagt man [Kukuruza](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F).)

Comment: @Stephie: Sorry, ich sollte wohl schlafen gehen. Ich habe Osten und Westen verwechselt (und nun korrigiert). Der Name kommt aus dem Osten und ist im Burgenland und in der Steiermark allgemein bekannt. Ich weiß aber nicht, ob »Kukuruz« auch in Tirol noch bekannt ist.

Comment: Laut Wikipedia ist die "Westgrenze" irgendwo in Altbayern, also im östlichen Teil Bayerns.  Schlaf' gut!

Comment: Hm, ich werfe dann doch mal "Krummbeere" ein, wie die Kartoffel in der Pfalz genannt wird. Ist das jetzt ne Abwandlung von Grumba/Grombira oder eher umgekehrt?

Comment: @Gerhard: Einigen wir uns auf "Varianten desselben Themas"?

Comment: Der Name "Apfel" kommt nicht daher, dass die Früchte einem Apfel ähnlich sehen. Früher war der Begriff "Apfel" ein allgemeiner Begriff für "Frucht". Daher der "Paradies-Apfel" (eine Frucht so rot, wie man sie sich im Paradies vorstellt), der "Erd-Apfel" (eine Frucht, die unter der Erde wächst) und als englisches Beispiel "Pineapple"

Comment: @Gerald: Die Schreibweise "Krummbeere", "Grumba" oder "Grombira" ist wohl eher zufällig. Der erste Wortbestandteil bedeutet "Krume" wie in "Ackerkrume" oder "Grund" - jedesmal also "Erde". Der zweite ist "Beere" (passend zu den kleinen giftigen oberirdischen Kartoffelfrüchten) oder "Birne" (passend zur Größe und Konsistenz der großen unterirdischen Knollen).

Answer (score 4):

Erst mal zur konkreten Frage: Es stimmt nur halb. Das Wort *Paradeiser* ist längst nicht in ganz Österreich verbreitet, sondern vor allem im Osten, der aber besonders wichtig ist, weil dort die meisten Menschen leben und dort Wien liegt. Ich habe vier Jahre in Wien gelebt und in dieser Zeit festgestellt, dass das Wort ebenso wie viele weitere typisch Wiener Wörter auf dem Rückzug ist. Das kann man u. a. daran erkennen, dass es in Zusammensetzungen schon völlig ungebräuchlich ist. Auch die Minderheit, die noch *Paradeiser* sagt, sagt größtenteils *Tomatensoße*, *Tomatensuppe*, *Tomatenketchup* usw. Das Wort *Paradeiser* wird in Wien von praktisch allen Einwohnern verstanden; benutzt wird es vor allem von älteren Menschen, die in der Region aufgewachsen sind.

Das Wort ist offensichtlich mit dem älteren Wort *Paradiesapfel* verwandt, einer früher auch in Deutschland verbreiteten Bezeichnung für Tomaten. Im Osten Österreichs hat es vermutlich deshalb länger überlebt, weil das ungarische Wort für *Tomate* *paradicsom* ist. (Wien ist nur etwa 70 km von der ungarischen Grenze entfernt.) Überhaupt gibt es in Wien noch zahlreiche lokale Ausdrücke für Nahrungsmittel, die offensichtlich mit entsprechenden tschechischen, slowakischen oder ungarischen Wörtern verwandt sind.

Zum allgemeinen Hintergrund:

Viele Wörter heißen in deutschen Dialekten ganz unterschiedlich, und manchmal hat das zu Alternativausdrücken (Schreiner/Tischler) oder Minderheitsvarianten (Erdapfel statt Kartoffel) im Hochdeutsch geführt. Österreich deckt nur einen kleinen Teil des deutschen Sprachraums ab. Da Dialekt und Umgangssprache die Schriftsprache beeinflussen, hat sich in Österreich (ähnlich wie in der Schweiz) eine eigene Varietät des Deutschen gebildet. Diese wird vom bevölkerungsstärkeren Osten geprägt, und vor allem von der Hauptstadt Wien. Weil Wien am Ostrand des Landes liegt, in der extremen Peripherie des deutschen Sprachraums, gibt es dort einige Ausdrücke, die weder in Deutschland noch in der Schweiz vorkommen, also spezifisch österreichisch sind. Das heißt noch nicht, dass sie auch im Westen des Landes, z. B. in Salzburg, gebräuchlich sind. Allerdings liest man dort in Wien erscheinende Zeitungen und schaut in Wien produziertes Fernsehen. Auch ist die Mobilität innerhalb Österreichs größer als die zwischen Österreich und Deutschland. Aus diesen Gründen werden diese ost-österreichischen Ausdrücke in ganz Österreich verstanden, während ein Deutscher oder Schweizer evtl. nachfragen muss, was gemeint ist. (Genau so, wie wir das alle von Wörtern aus fremden Dialekten kennen.) Das ist der Grund, warum österreichisches Deutsch sich ziemlich deutlich vom süddeutschen Hochdeutsch unterscheidet.

Insgesamt sind die Unterschiede zwischen österreichischem Hochdeutsch und südlichem Hochdeutsch nicht größer als die zwischen südlichem und nördlichem Hochdeutsch. Die Frage, ob es so etwas wie eine "österreichische Sprache" gibt oder geben sollte, ist eine politische und innerhalb Österreichs von einer gewissen Brisanz. Hintergrund ist, dass "deutsch" in den letzten Jahrhunderten ausgehend von einem rein sprachlich-kulturellen Begriff (der Österreich ganz selbstverständlich einschließt) auch eine nationale und schließlich eine nationalstaatliche Komponente erhalten hat (die Österreich mit Sicherheit nicht einschließt). Die Frage ist nun, böse gesagt, ob man diesen scheinbaren Widerspruch dauerhaft aushält, die kulturelle Verbindung mit Deutschland kappen und ähnlich wie Norwegen oder die Niederlande seine eigene Nationalsprache entwickeln will, oder ob man umgekehrt langfristig auf einen erneuten Anschluss Österreichs an Deutschland hinarbeitet.

Comment: Das Königreich Bayern wollt auch schon einmal bayrisch als die offizielle Sprache in den Schulen einführen. Die Idee wurde aber von der Verwaltungsbehörde nicht angenommen.Da Oberösterreich in der Vergangenheit auch zu Bayern gehörte, spricht man dort auch im Grunde genommen bayrisch. Als ich nach jahrelanger Abwesendheit wieder meinen Geburtsort besuchte, war man dort überrascht,dass ich den lokalen Dialekt noch sprach ("Du vaschtest ja no' bayrisch?"). Es gibt im Grunde genommen keinen österreichischen Dialekt, sondern eine Mehrzahl von regionalen Dialekten. Der Unterschied zwischen Tiroleri

Comment: Natürlich gibt es keinen einzelnen österreichischen Dialekt, sondern viele lokale Dialekte - genau so, wie auch in der Schweiz und in Deutschand. Die deutschen Dialekte in Österreich (es gibt auch slowenische) sind mit Ausnahme von Vorarlberg bairische Dialekte (mit *i*), genauso wie die in der südlichen Hälfte des deutschen Bundeslands Bayern (mit *y*). (Das Fränkische in Nordbayern ist nicht bairisch.) In Vorarlberg, der Schweiz, Schwaben, Baden und dem Elsass spricht man aber die ganz anderen alemannischen Dialekte. Dazwischen (Tirol, Allgäu) gibt es eine Übergangszone mit Mischdialekten.

Comment: Der letzte Satz mit dem *Anschluss* ist politisch schon sehr heftig, und ich weis ehrlich gesagt nicht ganz, was ich davon halten soll. Das Wort »Anschluss« hat, wie du sicherlich weist, eine sehr dunkelbraune Vergangenheit, gerade in Verhältnis zwischen Österreich und Deutschland. Immerhin hat der Anschluss Österreichs an Deutschland im Jahr 1938 dazu geführt, dass Österreich 7 Jahre lang nicht existiert hat.

Comment: Zum Wien-Zentrismus und dem sprachlichen Ost-West-Unterschied in Österreich: Österreich hat 8,70 Mio Einwohner. Davon leben 1,84 Mio (21,1%) allein in Wien. In den östlichen Bundesländern Niederösterreich (1,65 Mio), Oberösterreich (1,45 Mio), Burgenland (0,29 Mio) und Steiermark (1,23 Mio) und eben Wien (1,84) leben insgesamt 6,46 Mio Menschen, das sind 74,3 % aller Einwohner. Die westlichen Bundesländer (Salzburg 0,55, Kärnten 0,56, Tirol 0,74, Vorarlberg 0,38) stellen zusammen mit 2,23 Mio Einwohnern gerade mal 25,6% aller Einwohner. (Alle Zahlen: Stand vom 1.1.2016)

Comment: (Fortsetzung): Allein der Ballungsraum Wien (Wien + verflochtenes Umland laut Eurostat-Definition) hat ca. 2,7 Mio Einwohner, also mehr als der ganze Westen Österreichs. Daher ist es nicht verwunderlich, dass die ostösterreichische Umgangssprache im ganzen Lang dominiert, so wie es auch nicht verwunderlich ist, dass das deutsch(ländisch)e Deutsch den gesamten deutschen Sprachraum dominiert.

Comment: Mein Ziel mit dem "Anschluss"-Satz war es, zu verdeutlichen, in welchem Minenfeld sich in Österreich die Sprachpolitik bewegt. Am einen Ende das Unterrichtsfach "Unterrichtssprache" und am andern eben der Anschluss. Es ist ja kaum möglich, etwas zur österreichischen Varietät des Deutschen zu sagen, ohne dass entweder die verbliebenen Deutschtümler in der FPÖ (die weniger Probleme mit den 7 Jahren ohne Österreich haben als mit der 2. Republik) oder die Befürworter einer völligen kulturellen Abkopplung sich dadurch bestätigt fühlen. Ist das "böse gesagt" davor nicht ausreichend?