# Warum heißen Paradeiser in Deutschland »Tomaten«?

Tags: etymology, austrian

In [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22138/warum-hei%C3%9Fen-tomaten-in-%C3%96sterreich-paradeiser) wurde die Etymologie des Wortes »Paradeiser« (österreichischer Name für *Solanum lycopersicum*) behandelt. Während ich es ziemlich einfach finde, die Herkunft dieses Wortes abzuleiten, gelingt es mir nicht einmal ansatzweise, für die Herkunft von »Tomate« eine Erklärung zu finden.

Also: Warum heißen Paradeiser in Deutschland »Tomaten«?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Tomate** geht laut verschiedenen Quellen auf den aztekischen Namen zurück der entweder als

- tomatl<sub>*[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tomate)*,*[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GT06074#XGT06074)*</sub> (*[green husk tomato](http://whp.uoregon.edu/dictionaries/nahuatl/index.lasso)*) oder
- xitomatl<sub>*[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomate)*</sub> (*[red tomato](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/xitomatl)*)

angegeben wird.

Ähnlich wie bei [Kakao](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kakao) (cacao / cacahuatl) wurde hier nur der ursprüngliche Name ein wenig "aussprechbarer".